# If unique element clicked/If clicked outside of div (including another unique element)

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to toggle a class based off what's clicked. Say for an example, I have this:

```
<div id="element_1"> <!-- notice unique id attached to the end -->
   <button>My Button</button>
   <div class="hidden_wrapper">
      <span>Something</span>
      <span>Something else</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

To my understanding, I can do something like this to trigger that unique ID (untested):

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^=element] button", function() { $('[id^=element] hidden_wrapper').toggleClass('some_class'); });
```

What I'd like is to toggle that class under that unique ID (which will actually remove the class) if anything outside of my `#element_1 .hidden_wrapper` is clicked

Could someone please shed some light here?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a click handler for the entire document. In that handler, toggle the class on all elements except the target. Here's a quick-and-dirty version; more elegant approaches are possible.

```
$("html").on("click", function() {
    $(".hidden_wrapper").toggleClass("some_class");
    $(this).next().toggleClass("some_class");
})
```

This is inelegant because

- it toggles the element you don't want changed twice (kind of like a double negative)
- it depends on the element being the next sibling of the button.

Both problems easily fixed with a bit more code.